# How to change a foreignkey field back to null?

Tags: python, django, database

Pretty new to Django. I am trying to switch the `ForeignKey` field `student_information.project` back to a null value. As well my `student_remove` object doesn't seem to be defining properly as 'Remove' should be an object.

Error Code

```
AttributeError at /project_list/projects/1/

type object 'Student_Information' has no attribute 'student_remove'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/project_list/projects/1/?Remove=sathya
Django Version:     1.10.5
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

type object 'Student_Information' has no attribute 'student_remove'

Exception Location: /media/rms/Sathya's Dr/mysite/projects/views.py in post_detail, line 27
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.12
```

My views.py

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
post = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
students = Student_Information.objects.filter(project=post)
if request.GET.get('Remove'):
    Remove = request.GET.get('Remove')      
    obj = Student_Information.objects.get(RCSID=Remove)
    #obj.project = None
return render(request, 'projects/post_detail.html', {'post': post, 'students': students})

obj = Student_Information.objects.get(RCSID=Remove)
```

is throwing an, should specify that RCSID is a foreignkey, it seems like it's trying to find a primary key of 'sathya' where it should just get a string. How do I make it match the string? As if RCSID is automatically RCSID_id.

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sathya'
```

Comment: Thank you nik_m, I'll get used to the formatting in no time.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear. `Student_Information` model doesn't have any field named `student_remove`.

Apart from that, there are so many things wrong with your code.

- In Django, you don't update the Model class. You update an instance of Model class. Records are saved as instances of Model class. So line `Student_Information.student_remove.project = "---------"`, needs to be fixed.
- `student_information.project` can be set to null by simply calling `student_information.project = None`. But here `student_information` is an instance of `Student_Information` model.
- `filter` returns a `Queryset`, not an instance.
- You need to call `save` on the Model instance to update it in the database.

I would recommend you to go through official [polls app tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I adjusted my code and am getting more errors. I'd appreciate if you would bare with me for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by passing id instead of RCSID so that they matched. Easy fix.